# while overloading new if i delete an object pointer does it also deallocate the memory given dynamically to data members?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
class quasar{
    int quark;
    int *series;
    
    public:
    quasar(){
        quark=0;
        
    }
    quasar(int a){
        quark=a;
    }
    void *operator new(size_t){
       quasar*p;
       p=(quasar*)malloc(sizeof(quasar));
       p->series=new int[5];
        
        
        return p;

        
        
        
    }
    void operator delete(void *n){
        
        free(n);
        
    }
    void  input(){
        cout<<"enter your values\n";
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            cin>>series[i];
        }
    }
    void display(){
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            cout<<series[i];
        }
    }
};
int main(){
    quasar *q=new quasar;
    q->input();
    q->display();
    cout<<endl;
    delete q;
    q->display();

    
    

}
```

IN the code above when i overload new and delete operators i have also dynamically allocated memory to a data member pointer "series".so when i  delete the object pointer does the memory allocated to the data member pointer i.e. series in this code gets deallocated too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the series won't be deleted, you have to explicitly delete a pointer.
You can do that in a destructor like this:

```cpp
~quasar() {
  delete[] series;
}
```

You can also only add this to your delete-operator `delete[] series;`, but then it will only be deleted if you are working with a pointer to a quasar object.

You might want to call first `q->display()` and then delete it, or you will access an already deleted object.